# tortoise svn delete local file

Tags: tortoisesvn

i am new to  tortoise svn, and im working on a group project. the main files are located on a separate server. how can i delete any working folders on my machine without affecting the files on the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting your local working folders would never delete the files in svn server unless you do an svn commit to the server. So you can safely delete the working folders on your machine

Answer (score 1):

You can delete the folders/files on your machine - as long as you don't tell SVN the server will never know.  Which means - just don't Commit and you should be fine.

When i'm learning an new source control system, i usually will zip the local directory before i delete ... just incase i screw up.  Then after i'm sure i didn't screw up I stop doing the zips.